# ng-route with the same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have an API with two routes `/api/new` `/api/old`.
Items is the angular factory for requesting the api (`$http.get()`).

In controller by default I request the `/api/new`.

In the app I have two buttons New and Old.

I was thinking to listen to `$locationChangeStart` and load the Items again, but as I searched this seems not to be a best practice.

Its better to use `ng-click('old')` or `ng-click('new')` to fetch the data?

Can someone explain me whats the best practice on achiving this?

PS. I want to keep just one controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using *angular-router*. *angular-ui-router* is much better. There you can use

```
        .state('new', {
            url: '/new',
            templateUrl: 'views/view.html',
            controller: 'YourCtrl',
            data: {
                action: 'new'
            }
        })

        .state('old', {
            url: '/old',
            templateUrl: 'views/view.html',
            controller: 'YourCtrl',
            data: {
                action: 'old'
            }
        })
```

In the controller you can access the flag by `$state.$current.data.action`.

Comment: But its possible to use same controller?

Comment: Sure. The only condition that the states should differ by the path and the name.

Comment: Please, check my answer once again. I've corrected it. First time I suggested solution of another problem.